# how to show markdown preview in side panel using tasks.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-snippets

I have test.md file, and I want to show its preview using tasks.json without opening that test.md file in editor in vs code.

also what is command used in tasks.json for opening markdown preview?

How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: why a task and not a keyboard shortcut? I don't think tasks can do this (though I might be wrong)

Comment: @starball, because my requirement is different.

Comment: can you provide more information about what your goals are? That could help to understand why you have your requirement. Maybe there are other ways to achieve your underlying goal.